# Activate "Focus follows selection" in Xcode 9 beta 5?

Tags: xcode9-beta5

I used Focus Follows Selection in Xcode 8 and loved it.

I cannot find it anymore in Xcode 9 beta 5... When I search Xcode 9 help gives me this result: (where it actually was inside of Xcode 8)

---

You can focus attention on the code you’re currently editing, easily identifying where it begins and ends, by highlighting the current scope in the source editor.

￼
[Click here to see Apple Help screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP7lO.png)

- Click anywhere in the source editor.
- Choose Editor > Code Folding > Focus Follows Selection.

---

But the option seems to have moved or been removed.

It would greatly help me if anyone would know how to activate it inside of Xcode 9 beta 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They rewrote the editor. Try `cmd` + `mouse over` on the func / class / struct / var keywords. You should get a similar behaviour.

[image]